# How does an array of Objects contain primitive values?

Tags: java, object, primitive

```
public class Main {
    public static Object [] objArr = new Object[1];

    public static void main (String [] args) {
        objArr[0] = 4.20; // double value
        System.out.println("MEMES "  + Arrays.toString(objArr));
    }
}
```

The output displays "MEMES 4.20" correctly. 
My question is, how does the Object class contain primitive values? I thought primitive values are not subclasses of Java Object classes.

Comment: [Autoboxing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html).

Comment: It doesn't. It will contains objects, specifically a `Double` in this case. That's called [autoboxing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html).